# Where to put "FASTLANE_SESSION" value?

Tags: fastlane

I'm using **fastlane** with **Fastfile** and **Appfile**

According [this](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/spaceship#2-step-verification) doc, i did create *FASTLANE_SESSION* variable in order to not enter a two-factor verification password every buildtime. But can't figure out where and how to put it to make it work. I don't use CI service, only fastlane in command line to deploy my ios build. Help please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run and follow the instructions: `fastlane spaceauth -u some@email.com`

When asked to copy the session, you can just say no. Fastlane will store it on your Mac.

You should really consider creating an API Key. Then you will avoid this.

Docs: https://docs.fastlane.tools/app-store-connect-api/#creating-an-app-store-connect-api-key

Comment: I did edit my question. Need it to not enter two factor verification password every time.

Answer (score 3):

You need `FASTLANE_SESSION` available as an environment variable. If you're only running on command line you can do `export FASTLANE_SESSION='<your-session>'` and the next time you run the lanes that require the session should work.

Comment: Making `export..` every time before build is not convenience. I want to place it somewhere in Appfile or Fastfile or else, but need to know where and how.